# I have a problem When i Install Material UI in the application in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, installation, material-ui

```
PS C:\.............../app_1> npm install @mui/material
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @testing-library/react@13.4.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"17.0.2" from react-dom@17.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!     react-dom@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer react-dom@"^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from @mui/material@5.11.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       @mui/material@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!     2 more (@mui/base, react-transition-group)
npm ERR!   peer react@">= 16" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!     react-scripts@"5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   8 more (the root project, @mui/material, @mui/base, @mui/system, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!   @testing-library/react@"^13.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!     @testing-library/react@"^13.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Christos\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-14T18_36_04_214Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Christos\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-14T18_36_04_214Z-debug-0.log
```

//////////////////////////
I have changed the Version of React to 17.0.2
and update the index.js

Answer (score 0):

`@testing-library/react@13.4.0` requires `react@^18.0.0`

You have `react@17.0.2`

Either install `react@18`

Or install `@testing-library/react@12.1.5`

Comment: if i do that material UI does not run